# What would an idiomatic, monadic version of maximumBy look like?

Tags: haskell, monads

How can I get a maximum element of an effectful container where computing attribute to compare against also triggers an effect?

There has to be more readable way of doing things like:

```
latest dir = Turtle.fold (z (ls dir)) Fold.maximum

z :: MonadIO m => m Turtle.FilePath -> m (UTCTime, Turtle.FilePath)
z mx = do
    x <- mx
    d <- datefile x
    return (d, x)
```

I used overloaded version rather than non-overloaded `maximumBy` but the latter seems better suite for ad-hoc attribute selection.

How can I be more methodic in solving similar problems?

Comment: What would the type signature of your monadic `maximumBy` be?

Comment: Translating from non-monadic to monadic functions is often useful, especially when the function in question is lazy in some interesting way. For example, `ifM` is useful and has to be written by hand (as opposed to, say, `liftA3 if'`), because it will avoid doing one or the other of the effects in the two branches. But `maximumBy` has to look at the entire list; so there's no interesting laziness to preserve. Just use standard monadic combinators like `mapM` to do all the effects up front, then do your pure calculation afterwards.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but will this approach allow strict folds to run without space leaks?

Comment: @sevo Good point, that's another consideration that may make it worthwhile to hand-roll a monadic version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I know nothing about Turtle; no idea whether this fits well with the rest of the Turtle ecosystem. But since you convinced me in the comments that `maximumByM` is worth writing by hand, here's how I would do it:

```
maximumOnM :: (Monad m, Ord b) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m a
maximumOnM cmp [x] = return x -- skip the effects if there's no need for comparison
maximumOnM cmp (x:xs) = cmp x >>= \b -> go x b xs where
    go x b [] = return x
    go x b (x':xs) = do
        b' <- cmp x'
        if b < b' then go x' b' xs else go x b xs
```

I generally prefer the *On versions of things -- which take a function that maps to an `Ord`erable element -- to the *By versions -- which take a function that does the comparison directly. A `maximumByM` would be similar but have a type like `Monad m => (a -> a -> m Ordering) -> [a] -> m a`, but this would likely force you to redo effects for each `a`, and I'm guessing it's not what you want. I find *On more often matches with the thing I want to do and the performance characteristics I want.

Comment: Why not upgrade from `Fold` to `FoldM`?

Comment: @dfeuer I don't really understand the question.

Comment: The `Fold.maximum` in the question comes from `foldl-Control.Foldl`, which offers a `Fold` type (whose `fold` operation is re-exported by `Turtle`) but also a `FoldM` type. Both of these have `Applicative` instances to combine folds "in parallel". It should be possible to express the effectful maximum as a `FoldM`.

Comment: @dfeuer Sounds like a fun answer. You should add it!

Comment: I just did. It's fairly similar to yours, although I return a `Maybe`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already familiar with `Fold`, you might want to get to know `FoldM`, which is similar.

```
data FoldM m a b =
  -- FoldM step initial extract
  forall x . FoldM (x -> a -> m x) (m x) (x -> m b)
```

You can write:

```
maximumOnM ::
  (Ord b, Monad m)
  => (a -> m b) -> FoldM m a (Maybe a)
maximumOnM f = FoldM combine (pure Nothing) (fmap snd)
  where
    combine Nothing a = do
      f_a <- f a
      pure (Just (f_a, a))
    combine o@(Just (f_old, old)) new = do
      f_new <- f new
      if f_new > f_old
        then pure $ Just (f_new, new)
        else pure o
```

Now you can use `Foldl.foldM` to run the fold on a list (or other `Foldable` container). Like `Fold`, `FoldM` has an `Applicative` instance, so you can combine multiple effectful folds into one that interleaves the effects of each of them and combines their results.

Comment: Nice! `f a` effect in the first pattern is lazily evaluated! Is that guaranteed, though?

Comment: Applicative version is awesome, but can it break "stability" of results when they are equal in the eyes of combining function?

Comment: @sevo, I think I fixed the type error. Haven't tried compiling it yet. What do you mean about stability?

Comment: Since Applicative can run effects in parallel, the IO effects may be completed in different order than they appear in the input. In such case, of two "equal" elements, the one that appears first in the input should be always picked. I was wondering whether foldM has this property.

Comment: @sevo, the `Applicative` instance for `FoldM` is entirely deterministic. It runs the effects for an element in order, from left to right, then moves on to the next element.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to run effects on foldables using reducers package.

I'm not sure if it's correct, but it leverages existing combinators and instances (except for `Bounded (Maybe a)`).

```
import Data.Semigroup.Applicative (Ap(..))
import Data.Semigroup.Reducer (foldReduce)
import Data.Semigroup (Max(..))
import System.IO (withFile, hFileSize, IOMode(..))

-- | maxLength
--
-- >>> getMax $ maxLength ["abc","a","hello",""]
-- 5
maxLength :: [String] -> (Max Int)
maxLength = foldReduce . map (length)

-- | maxLengthIO
--
-- Note, this runs IO...
--
-- >>> (getAp $ maxLengthIO ["package.yaml", "src/Lib.hs"]) >>= return . getMax
-- Just 1212
--
-- >>> (getAp $ maxLengthIO []) >>= return . getMax
-- Nothing
maxLengthIO :: [String] -> Ap IO (Max (Maybe Integer))
maxLengthIO xs = foldReduce (map (fmap Just . f) xs) where
    f :: String -> IO Integer
    f s = withFile s ReadMode hFileSize

instance Ord a => Bounded (Maybe a) where
    maxBound = Nothing
    minBound = Nothing
```

Comment: Orphan instances are evil, and that instance doesn't even make sense. You probably meant `minBound = Nothing; maxBound = Just maxBound`

Comment: Per my answer on your other question, I would recommend `maxLengthIO = foldMap (Ap . fmap Finite . f)`, using Data.Monoid.Inf.Finite. Way fewer gymnastics required, plus it uses the modern `Foldable` idiom that has supplanted the reducers package.

Comment: Please allow some time whyle my brain tries to comprehend but this looks like perfect answer! I had no idea that Foldable has supplanted the reducers package!